# Limit of $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} n(x^{(1/n)}-1)$ for $x \in (0,1]$

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to find the limit of $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n\left(x^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)$
This is a part of a larger homework question on uniform convergence of sequences of functions.

It has been a while since I did basic calculus so I don't know how to get started with this (though I suspect it is easy).

Comment: Is it $x\to\infty$ or $n\to\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that the limit

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n\left(x^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)$$

is equivalent to the limit

$$\lim_{n \to 0} \frac{\left(x^{n}-1\right)}{n}$$

Thus, using L'Hospital's Rule, we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} n\left(x^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)&=\lim_{n \to 0} \frac{\left(x^{n}-1\right)}{n}\\
&=\lim_{n \to 0} \frac{\frac{d}{dn}\left(x^{n}-1\right)}{\frac{d}{dn}n}\\
&=\lim_{n \to 0} \frac{x^n \log(x)}{1}\\
&=\log(x)
\end{align}$$

Comment: although your answer is conceptually correct, it lack rigor as the use of $d/dn$ is unjustified when $n$ is an integer.

Comment: It is much more difficult to rigorously prove $$\frac{d}{dn}\,x^{n}=x^{n}\log x$$ for real $n$ than to prove the existence of the limit here based on simple algebra when $n$ is assumed positive integer.  I have indicated this kind of approach in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{n \to \infty} n (x^ \frac 1 n -1) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {x^ \frac 1 n -1} {\frac 1 n} = \frac {{\Bbb d} x^y} {\Bbb d y} (0) = (x^y \ln x) (0) = \ln x$, where $\ln$ is the natural logarithm.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is to show that the limit exists for all $x > 0$ and defines a function $f(x)$ and show that it has the following properties:
$$f(xy) = f(x) + f(y), f(1) = 0, f'(x) = \frac{1}{x}$$ I have given more details of this approach in my [blog post](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-2_10.html) (search for "Logarithm as a Limit").